# what's different between each and collect method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, each, collect

From this code I don't know the difference between the two methods, `collect` and `each`.

```
a = ["L","Z","J"].collect{|x| puts x.succ} #=> M AA K 
print  a.class  #=> Array

b = ["L","Z","J"].each{|x| puts x.succ} #=> M AA K
print  b.class #=> Array
```

Comment: Why are you `print`ing `a.class`, `b.class`? Print `a` and `b` instead, and it will be clear. See Refactor's answer. I think you are confusing the effect of your two one-liners, which are the same, and the return value of them, which are different.

Comment: Use `p` instead of `print` when you want to see the content of an object. I forgot to mention that. Try `p a` and `p b` in you code above.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`Array#each` takes an array and applies the given block over all items. It doesn't affect the array or creates a new object. It is just a way of looping over items. Also it returns self.

```
  arr=[1,2,3,4]
  arr.each {|x| puts x*2}
```

Prints 2,4,6,8 and returns [1,2,3,4] no matter what

`Array#collect` is same as `Array#map` and it applies the given block of code on all the items and returns the new array. simply put **'Projects each element of a sequence into a new form'**

```
  arr.collect {|x| x*2}
```

Returns [2,4,6,8]

And In your code

```
 a = ["L","Z","J"].collect{|x| puts x.succ} #=> M AA K
```

a is an Array but it is actually an array of Nil's **[nil,nil,nil]** because `puts x.succ` returns `nil` (even though it prints M AA K).

And

```
 b = ["L","Z","J"].each{|x| puts x.succ} #=> M AA K
```

also is an Array. But its value is ["L","Z","J"], because it returns self.

Answer (score 41):

`Array#each` just takes each element and puts it into the block, then returns the original array. `Array#collect` takes each element and puts it into a new array that gets returned:

```
[1, 2, 3].each { |x| x + 1 }    #=> [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3].collect { |x| x + 1 } #=> [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

`each` is for when you want to iterate over an array, and do whatever you want in each iteration. In most (imperative) languages, this is the "one size fits all" hammer that programmers reach for when you need to process a list.

For more functional languages, you only do this sort of generic iteration if you can't do it any other way. Most of the time, either map or reduce will be more appropriate (collect and inject in ruby)

`collect` is for when you want to turn one array into another array

`inject` is for when you want to turn an array into a single value

Answer (score 2):

Here are the two source code snippets, according to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html)...

```
VALUE
rb_ary_each(VALUE ary)
{
    long i;

    RETURN_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_yield(RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i]);
    }
    return ary;
}

# .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....

static VALUE
rb_ary_collect(VALUE ary)
{
    long i;
    VALUE collect;

    RETURN_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0);
    collect = rb_ary_new2(RARRAY_LEN(ary));
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_ary_push(collect, rb_yield(RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i]));
    }
    return collect;
}
```

`rb_yield()` returns the value returned by the block ([see also this blog post on metaprogramming](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/metaprogramming-in-the-ruby-c-api-part-one-blocks/)).

So `each` just *yields* and returns the original array, while `collect` creates a new array and pushes the results of the block into it; then it returns this new array.

Source snippets: [each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.src/M000231.html), [collect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.src/M000247.html)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is what it returns. In your example above 
`a == [nil,nil,nil]` (the value of puts x.succ) while `b == ["L", "Z", "J"]` (the original array)

From the ruby-doc, collect does the following:

> Invokes block once for each element of
>   self. Creates a new array containing
>   the values returned by the block.

Each always returns the original array. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Each is a method defined by all classes that include the Enumerable module. `Object.each`returns a `Enumerable::Enumerator` Object. This is what other Enumerable methods use to iterate through the object. `each` methods of each class behaves differently.

In Array class when a block is passed to `each`, it performs statements of the block on each element, but in the end returns self.This is useful when you don't need an array, but you maybe just want to choose elements from the array and use the as arguments to other methods. `inspect` and `map` return a new array with return values of execution of the block on each element. You can use `map!` and `collect!` to perform operations on the original array.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier way to understand it would be as below:

```
nums = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
square = nums.each { |num| num ** 2 } # => [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Instead, if you use collect:

```
square = nums.collect { |num| num ** 2 } # => [1, 1, 4, 9, 25]
```

And plus, you can use `.collect!` to mutate the original array.