# Ruby array: change string element format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of string which contains the "*firstname.lastname*" strings:

```
customers = ["aaa.bbb", "ccc.ddd", "www.uuu", "iii.oooo", ...]
```

Now, I would like to transfer each element's string format in the array by removing the "**.**" and use **space** instead. That's I want the array to be:

```
customers = ["aaa bbb", "ccc ddd", "www uuu", "iii oooo", ...]
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

**---------------- MORE -------------------**

And how about my case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011780/ruby-array-convert-to-two-arrays-in-my-case)

Answer (score 7):

```
customers.collect!{|name| name.gsub(/\./, " ")}
```

**Update**

@tadman has it, here's my benchmarking FWIW

```
require 'benchmark'

customers = []
500000.times { customers << "john.doe" }

Benchmark.bm do|b|
  b.report("+= ") do
    # customers.collect!{|name| name.gsub(/\./, " ")} # 2.414220
    # customers.each { |c| c.gsub!(/\./, ' ') } # 2.223308
    customers.each { |c| c.tr!('.', ' ') } # 0.379226
  end
end
```

Comment: Is .collect method more efficient than .each method ?

Comment: @Mellon, collect! is method for in-place working and after that you get changed collection. In case of `each` using you have to collect changed values by hand and that definitely not so efficent

Comment: You don't necessarily need to `collect` if you're iterating and mangling in-place.

Comment: How about my case here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011780/ruby-array-convert-to-two-arrays-in-my-case

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is the most *efficient*, but it does the job:

```
customers.collect!{ |name| name.split('.').join(' ') }
```

Comment: Is .collect method more efficient than .each method ?

Comment: The don't do the same thing. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347949/whats-different-between-each-and-collect-method-in-ruby

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. `split` generates an Array object with multiple strings in it which are then discarded when the `join` operation occurs. `gsub!` will convert in-place, modifying the same object, so there's no garbage.

Comment: @tadman that may be true, but "efficient" is kind of ambiguous - does it mean fast or memory efficient? Split and join may use more memory but may still be faster. I don't know that, hence my qualifier in the answer, but I doubt it amounts to a "really bad" idea. Maybe just a "somewhat sloppy" idea :)

Comment: Thanks all, how about my case here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011780/ruby-array-convert-to-two-arrays-in-my-case

Comment: The results of trying it are surprising to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just modify each value in-place:

```
customers.each { |c| c.gsub!(/\./, ' ') }
```

The alternatives, like `collect!` are more appropriate when you're switching the kind of object, not just altering the content of an existing object.

Note that this will mangle the original input, so if the String values in `customers` are frozen or need to be preserved in their initial form this won't work. This is probably not the case, but it is important to keep this in mind.

**Update:** After some benchmarking I've come to the conclusion that the fastest way to perform this operation is:

```
customers.each { |c| c.tr!('.', ' ') }
```

For those that are curious, [here's a benchmark scaffold](https://gist.github.com/1339615) to experiment with.

```
  #     user     system      total        real
  # 0.740000   0.020000   0.760000 (  0.991042)
  list.each { |c| c.gsub!(/\./, ' ') }

  # 0.680000   0.010000   0.690000 (  1.011136)
  list.collect! { |c| c.gsub(/\./, ' ') }

  # 0.490000   0.020000   0.510000 (  0.628354)
  list.collect!{ |c| c.split('.').join(' ') }

  # 0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.103968)
  list.collect!{ |c| c.tr!('.', ' ') }
```

Comment: Correct you are. `tr!` it is.

Comment: Yay, second place! :) Nice solution