# Ruby array, convert to two arrays in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of string which contains the "*firstname.lastname?some.xx*" format strings:

```
customers = ["aaa.bbb?q21.dd", "ccc.ddd?ew3.yt", "www.uuu?nbg.xcv", ...]
```

Now, I would like to use this array to produce two arrays, with:

- the element of the 1st array has only the string before "?" and replace the "**.**" to a **space**.
- the element of the 2nd array is the string after "**?**" and include "**?**"

That's **I want to produce the following two arrays from the** `customers` **array**:

```
1st_arr = ["aaa bbb", "ccc ddd", "www uuu", ...]

2nd_arr = ["?q21.dd", "?ew3.yt", "?nbg.xcv", ...]
```

**What is the most efficient way to do it** if I use `customers` array as an *argument* of a method?

```
def produce_two_arr customers
  #What is the most efficient way to produce the two arrays

  #What I did:
  1st_arr = Array.new
  2nd_arr = Array.new
  customers.each do |el|
    1st_Str, 2nd_Str=el.split('?')

    1st_arr << 1st_str.gsub(/\./, " ")
    2nd_arr << "?"+2nd_str
  end

  p 1st_arr
  p 2nd_arr
end
```

Comment: it seems pretty trivial, where exactly do you get stuck? show some code.

Comment: I agree; along with your previous question, I'd suggest making an effort first. You know how to create arrays, you know a few ways to iterate, you know how to do a replace. There's a [split](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/split) method on string.

Comment: I was about to post my answer, but agree. Look into the array (hint: map) and string documentation.

Comment: It looks like you edited the question.  What kind of efficiency are you asking for: simplest code or fastest execution time?

Comment: Yep, I added my code already. I am looking for both, simplest code and fastest execution one. Just wanna learn from more experienced one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional approach: when you are generating results inside a loop but you want them to be split in different arrays, [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-transpose) comes handy:

```
ary1, ary2 = customers.map do |customer|
  a, b = customer.split("?", 2)
  [a.gsub(".", " "), "?" + b]
end.transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Anytime you're building an array from another, `reduce` (a.k.a. `inject`) is a great help:</s>

But sometimes, a good ol' `map` is all you need (in this case, either one works because you're building an array of the same size):

```
a, b = customers.map do |customer|
  a, b = customer.split('?')
  [a.tr('.', ' '), "?#{b}"]
end.transpose
```

This is very efficient since you're only iterating through customers a single time and you are making efficient use of memory by not creating lots of extraneous strings and arrays through the `+` method.

Comment: Yeah, I think either option would work here. Map is probably clearer. I think I'll update.

Comment: no, no, you are now doing a map-inject frankenstein :-) Look at my answer, they are now equivalent. Note that you could always implement map with inject, but that's no reason to do it :-)

Comment: Not true; I think you may have caught an overly eager save.

Comment: oh, sorry. Indeed, I saw a .map do |result, costumer|.

Answer (score 0):

Array#collect is good for this type of thing:

```
arr1 = customers.collect{ |c| c.split("?").first.sub( ".", "" ) }
arr2 = customers.collect{ |c| "?" + c.split("?").last }
```

But, you have to do the initial c.split("?") twice. So, it's effecient from an amount of code point of view, but more CPU intensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
1st_arr = customers.collect{ |name| name.gsub(/\?.*\z/,'').gsub(/\./,' ') }

2nd_arr = customers.collect{ |name| name.match(/\?.*\z/)[0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1, array2 = customers.map{|el| el.sub('.', ' ').split /(?:\?)/}.transpose
```

Based on @Tokland 's code, but it avoids the extra variables (by using 'sub' instead of 'gsub') and the re-attaching of '?' (by using a non-capturing regex).